# Out of memory error - java heap space

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I was trying to compile the project for which i am writing a plugin. The project worked fine, compiled and ran no problems. But then i started getting out of memory error. It just compiled fine 1 minute ago. I even didnt change anything in the code. I was hunting down a bug so i wanted to switch to debug mode. SO i just started compiling in debug, but no neither normal nor debug will compile.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.XMLString.toString(XMLString.java:188)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.XMLAttributesImpl.getValue(XMLAttributesImpl.java:544)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy.getValue(AbstractSAXParser.java:2325)
at org.processmining.framework.packages.impl.PackageConfigPerister$ConfigHandler.startElement(PackageConfigPerister.java:159)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1358)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2781)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
at org.processmining.framework.packages.impl.PackageConfigPerister.read(PackageConfigPerister.java:65)
at org.processmining.framework.packages.impl.PackageConfigPerister.read(PackageConfigPerister.java:43)
at org.processmining.framework.packages.PackageManager.initialize(PackageManager.java:184)
at org.processmining.contexts.uitopia.packagemanager.PMController.<init>(PMController.java:23)
at org.processmining.contexts.uitopia.packagemanager.PMFrame.<init>(PMFrame.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.processmining.framework.boot.Boot.boot(Boot.java:274)
at org.processmining.contexts.uitopia.UI.main(UI.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Comment: You have a large XML document which is too large for it to parse. Normally IntelliJ will just ignore files which are too large, unless you don't have much memory it should prevent this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I solved it by increasing the memory it can use. It was set to 1G i gave it 3G and now it works.